# How to iterate over a List of Maps and extract a piece of data from each map

Tags: java, list, loops, dictionary

I am working on a Java method that receives two items from a Karate method (hopefully if you aren't familiar with Karate, this will still make sense since my question is more about the Java piece).

The Polyglot List is a list of Polyglot Maps. Really the list of maps is a json response from an API call done in Karate, but when it is passed to Java from Karate, it's received as a list of maps. I wrote a method a while back to iterate over the Polyglot List, extract an ID number from each list item, and then add the ID number to a new List of type Integer. This may seem like an extra step, but there is another json that has a different structure but I need to be able to compare just the ID numbers to see if the same Ids are present in each json.

So what I'm trying to do ultimately is extract those IDs so I can put them in a list, order them, and then compare them to another list of IDs.

The problem I'm hitting now is that my team is moving our automation into a CICD pipeline and the method that worked in IntelliJ is getting an error when run in cmd.

The code I was previously using:

```
for (Map<String, ?> rule : dbResponse) {
    System.out.println("Inside the for each loop...");
    Integer id = (Integer) rule.get("id");
    dbResponseIds.add(id);
}
```

Now this code is getting an error "org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.AssertionError" at the start of the for each loop. I put a print statement inside of the for each loop to double check where the error is occurring and indeed the print statement inside the loop is not printed. I thought maybe the issue was with the Map<String, ?> piece since dbResponse is technically a list of maps, but it was worked at the time, can't remember now exactly why.

Since it seems the for each loop syntax is off, I tried a new take:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dbResponse.size()); i++) {
    System.out.println("Inside the reg for loop.");
    System.out.println("Attempting to print index " + i + " of the dbResponse List.");
    // System.out.println(dbResponse[i]);
    System.out.println(dbResponse.get(i));
}
```

Now I'm able to get inside the loop, but the method is failing at the print System.out.println(dbResponse.get(i)) with the same error that was happening when using the for each loop. I think when I iterate over the list, I need to somehow go deeper a level to get the ID out of each map. I was able earlier to work out printing each element of a Map with help here https://www.techiedelight.com/print-all-keys-and-values-map-java/ but I'm not really sure how to go into the list then into the Map in one line as I'm iterating over each item. Thank you in advance for any help!

Looks like Stack Overflow is recommending this answer [Iterate over list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282327/iterate-over-list-of-maps) but looks like that's in JavaScript.

Update:
Here is the stack trace:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotMap$Cache.lookup(PolyglotMap.java:430)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotMap.<init>(PolyglotMap.java:87)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotMap.create(PolyglotMap.java:94)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotHostAccess.toMap(PolyglotHostAccess.java:113)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.asJavaObject(HostToTypeNode.java:399)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.convertImpl(HostToTypeNode.java:194)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.doCached(HostToTypeNode.java:118)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(HostToTypeNodeGen.java:91)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNodeGen.execute(HostToTypeNodeGen.java:50)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostLanguageService.toHostType(HostLanguageService.java:117)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotToHostNode.doDefault(PolyglotToHostNode.java:59)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotToHostNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(PolyglotToHostNodeGen.java:44)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotToHostNodeGen.execute(PolyglotToHostNodeGen.java:30)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList$Cache$GetNode.doCached(PolyglotList.java:282)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotListFactory$CacheFactory$GetNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(PolyglotListFactory.java:269)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotListFactory$CacheFactory$GetNodeGen.executeImpl(PolyglotListFactory.java:217)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.HostToGuestRootNode.execute(HostToGuestRootNode.java:125)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList.get(PolyglotList.java:103)
        at com.dell.insights.remediation.Utilities.matchRuleIdsByMap(Utilities.java:627)
        at <js> :program(Unnamed:1:0-62)
        at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:401)
        at com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.evalForValue(JsEngine.java:141)
        at com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.eval(JsEngine.java:137)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJs(ScenarioEngine.java:1252)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2205)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2124)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalAndCastTo(ScenarioEngine.java:1316)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.assign(ScenarioEngine.java:1349)
        at com.intuit.karate.ScenarioActions.def(ScenarioActions.java:188)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.StepRuntime.execute(StepRuntime.java:280)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioRuntime.execute(ScenarioRuntime.java:459)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioRuntime.run(ScenarioRuntime.java:402)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime.processScenario(FeatureRuntime.java:181)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioIterator.tryAdvance(ScenarioIterator.java:156)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:332)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:706)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime.run(FeatureRuntime.java:164)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.SyncExecutorService.execute(SyncExecutorService.java:70)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at com.intuit.karate.Suite.run(Suite.java:235)
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.parallel(Runner.java:575)
        at TestRunnerParallel.executeKarateTests(TestRunnerParallel.java:127)
        at TestRunnerParallel.testParallel(TestRunnerParallel.java:85)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSet.executeTestMethod(PojoTestSet.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSet.executeTestMethods(PojoTestSet.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSet.execute(PojoTestSet.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:113)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:206)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1166)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:120)
        at com.dell.MojoRunnerFunctional.execute(MojoRunnerFunctional.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Original Internal Error:
java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotMap$Cache.lookup(PolyglotMap.java:430)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotMap.<init>(PolyglotMap.java:87)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotMap.create(PolyglotMap.java:94)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotHostAccess.toMap(PolyglotHostAccess.java:113)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.asJavaObject(HostToTypeNode.java:399)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.convertImpl(HostToTypeNode.java:194)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.doCached(HostToTypeNode.java:118)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(HostToTypeNodeGen.java:91)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNodeGen.execute(HostToTypeNodeGen.java:50)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostLanguageService.toHostType(HostLanguageService.java:117)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotToHostNode.doDefault(PolyglotToHostNode.java:59)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotToHostNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(PolyglotToHostNodeGen.java:44)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotToHostNodeGen.execute(PolyglotToHostNodeGen.java:30)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList$Cache$GetNode.doCached(PolyglotList.java:282)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotListFactory$CacheFactory$GetNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(PolyglotListFactory.java:269)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotListFactory$CacheFactory$GetNodeGen.executeImpl(PolyglotListFactory.java:217)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.HostToGuestRootNode.execute(HostToGuestRootNode.java:125)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.call(DefaultCallTarget.java:102)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList.get(PolyglotList.java:103)
        at com.dell.insights.remediation.Utilities.matchRuleIdsByMap(Utilities.java:627)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostMethodDesc$SingleMethod$MHBase.invokeHandle(HostMethodDesc.java:284)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.GuestToHostCodeCache$1.executeImpl(GuestToHostCodeCache.java:98)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.GuestToHostRootNode.execute(GuestToHostRootNode.java:81)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultRuntimeAccessor$DefaultRuntimeSupport.callInlined(DefaultRuntimeAccessor.java:119)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.GuestToHostRootNode.guestToHostCall(GuestToHostRootNode.java:107)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostMethodDesc$SingleMethod$MHBase.invokeGuestToHost(HostMethodDesc.java:315)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNode.doInvoke(HostExecuteNode.java:828)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNode.doFixed(HostExecuteNode.java:132)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(HostExecuteNodeGen.java:140)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNodeGen.execute(HostExecuteNodeGen.java:95)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostObject.invokeMember(HostObject.java:441)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostObjectGen$InteropLibraryExports$Cached.invokeMemberNode_AndSpecialize(HostObjectGen.java:2695)
        at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostObjectGen$InteropLibraryExports$Cached.invokeMember(HostObjectGen.java:2677)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.interop.InteropLibrary$Asserts.invokeMember(InteropLibrary.java:3378)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.interop.InteropLibraryGen$CachedDispatch.invokeMember(InteropLibraryGen.java:8138)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode$ForeignInvokeNode.executeCall(JSFunctionCallNode.java:1478)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode.executeAndSpecialize(JSFunctionCallNode.java:305)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode.executeCall(JSFunctionCallNode.java:251)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode$InvokeNode.execute(JSFunctionCallNode.java:724)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.access.JSWriteCurrentFrameSlotNodeGen.execute_generic4(JSWriteCurrentFrameSlotNodeGen.java:163)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.access.JSWriteCurrentFrameSlotNodeGen.execute(JSWriteCurrentFrameSlotNodeGen.java:86)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.access.JSWriteCurrentFrameSlotNodeGen.executeVoid(JSWriteCurrentFrameSlotNodeGen.java:317)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.binary.DualNode.execute(DualNode.java:124)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.FunctionBodyNode.execute(FunctionBodyNode.java:73)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.FunctionRootNode.executeInRealm(FunctionRootNode.java:150)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.JavaScriptRealmBoundaryRootNode.execute(JavaScriptRealmBoundaryRootNode.java:93)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultDirectCallNode.call(DefaultDirectCallNode.java:59)
        at com.oracle.truffle.js.lang.JavaScriptLanguage$1.execute(JavaScriptLanguage.java:214)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)
        at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.call(DefaultCallTarget.java:102)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.eval(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1348)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextDispatch.eval(PolyglotContextDispatch.java:62)
        at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:375)
        at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:401)
        at com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.evalForValue(JsEngine.java:141)
        at com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.eval(JsEngine.java:137)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJs(ScenarioEngine.java:1252)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2205)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2124)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalAndCastTo(ScenarioEngine.java:1316)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.assign(ScenarioEngine.java:1349)
        at com.intuit.karate.ScenarioActions.def(ScenarioActions.java:188)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.StepRuntime.execute(StepRuntime.java:280)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioRuntime.execute(ScenarioRuntime.java:459)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioRuntime.run(ScenarioRuntime.java:402)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime.processScenario(FeatureRuntime.java:181)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioIterator.tryAdvance(ScenarioIterator.java:156)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:332)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:706)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureRuntime.run(FeatureRuntime.java:164)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.intuit.karate.core.SyncExecutorService.execute(SyncExecutorService.java:70)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at com.intuit.karate.Suite.run(Suite.java:235)
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.parallel(Runner.java:575)
        at TestRunnerParallel.executeKarateTests(TestRunnerParallel.java:127)
        at TestRunnerParallel.testParallel(TestRunnerParallel.java:85)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSet.executeTestMethod(PojoTestSet.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSet.executeTestMethods(PojoTestSet.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoTestSet.execute(PojoTestSet.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:113)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:206)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1166)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:120)
        at com.dell.MojoRunnerFunctional.execute(MojoRunnerFunctional.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: Attached Guest Language Frames (4)
```

Comment: _Why_  and _how_ the loop is failing at the print?  Any error message or unexpected result?

Comment: In the for each loop, it's failing at the for each statement. But in the regular for loop, it's able to get inside the for loop but failing at the statement to print the index, "System.out.println(dbResponse.get(i))"

Comment: What is the type of `dbResponse`? Is it `List<Map<String, ?>>`? It may help if you [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace. Are you using [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/)?

Comment: You said you get an AssertionError, and that it fails, but what *exactly* does the error say? What is the message? I find it hard to believe the AssertionError does not have a message that tells you more about what's wrong. You say it runs in your environment, but not on command line. Are you using the same JVM on command line as you do in your IDE?

Comment: @Abra yes, it is List<Map<String. ?>>    I will edit my question now to include the stack trace. Thank you for suggesting that, I'm still very new to this industry (only six months in) so it's good to know that's helpful. I do not know if GraalVM is being used to be honest, I'm not really familiar. I don't believe I remember installing anything like that so I would guess not but it's possible I suppose that it could be some sort of dependency nested in our pom.xml that maybe I'm not aware of.

Comment: @NickL I will edit my question to include the stack trace. Maybe I'm just not experienced enough to read the stack trace well enough to understand, but I'm not seeing anything more detailed than the assertion error I already included in my question. As far as if we are using the same JVM on command line as in the IDE, I do not know or know how to check. Unfortunately a lot of my team is out on leave right now so there aren't as many resources as usual to ask for help, but I'll see if someone might know tomorrow.

Comment: Ah I see. I have no experience with things you are using (Graal, PolyglotMap, Karate to Java) so I have no other suggestions. If it works in your IDE and not somewhere else, I still highly suspect that where it is working you are using a different version of something - probably different version of GraalVM. This could be a bug fixed in the version you are using, but still exists in the version where it doesn't work. I'm guessing here though, good luck solving.